# Could not make protractor-http-mock working, throws error "Module 'httpMock' is not available!"

Tags: protractor

I am trying to mock the http response using "protractor-http-mock ".

This is how I used this in my Tests

```
var mock = require('protractor-http-mock');
beforeEach(function() {
        mock([{
            request: {
                path: 'api/account/activate',
                method: 'PUT',
                //status: 204
            },
            response: {
                //data: {},
                status: 204
            }
        }]);
    });

expect(mock.requestsMade()).toEqual([
       { url : '/api/account/activate', method : 'PUT' }
    ]);
```

When I run my Tests it says - UnknownError: javascript error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'httpMock' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Also when I remove the expect part, it doesn't complain about anything but doesn't mock anything as well.

Could somebody with more knowledge help? I don't want to use - ngMockE2E, is there any third way of doing it?

Comment: Try adding a  `require('protractor-http-mock')` to `onPrepare()` in your protractor config.

Comment: I did same on conf.js -   onPrepare: function () {
        require('protractor-http-mock');
    }, but still no luck.

Comment: Could you try reinstalling `protractor-http-mock`? Also, which `protractor` version are you using? Thanks.

Comment: no this didn't help either, I am using protractor 1.8. I have created a gist for the same   -- https://gist.github.com/vineet-mrgreen/062ad46d3de0fd15428b. Is there anything incorrect in my file? Are the parameters am passing is incorrect or ?

Comment: Have you had any luck in resolving this? After extensive debugging (including the Protractor sources themselves), The only thing I can conclude is that the httpMock module is indeed created and injected when Protractor.get is called. However, placing breaks in the module itself clearly shows that it is never even being invoked or added the to the app. I have no idea where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the problem when `mock()` has not been called, but `mock.teardown()` was. In your case, you should put `tearDown()` into `afterEach()`:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    mock([{
        request: {
            path: 'api/account/activate',
            method: 'PUT',
        },
        response: {
            //data: {},
            status: 204
        }
    }]);

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('/');
    // wait before we get past loading stage, this together with ignoreSynchronization seems be a valid workaround for manually //boostrapping Angular when running Protractor
    browser.driver.wait(function () {
        return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
            return /\/\w+-\w+\//.test(url);
        });
    });
});

afterEach(function () {
    mock.teardown();
});
```

Also, few things to note that can help here:

- your protractor configuration should have `mocks` defined:

  ```
  mocks: {
      dir: "mocks",  // path to directory with mocks
      default: []
  },
  ```
- in `onPrepare()` in the protractor configuration, set the `.config`:

  ```
  require("protractor-http-mock").config = {
      rootDirectory: __dirname,
      protractorConfig: "protractor.conf.js"  // name of the config here
  };
  ```

Comment: did exactly same as mentioned above, but have some questions?  1. Why after each function? am not calling mock in every function, only 1 function will need mock. 2. why to define mocks separately? am calling it from inside spec file, do I really need to separate it because I haven't created any mock file as such. I re-installed app after these steps but still I get http-mock not available. here is my Conf file - https://gist.github.com/vineet-mrgreen/4831394d2035117fad19

Comment: I was stupid, I know why after each function. I didnt see before each .. well in my updated file am not using the mock in before each as I need it only for 1 function

Comment: @hny2015 sorry, I've just listed everything I have set and it is working for me..

Comment: can you share your conf file and mock file, so I see what am I doing wrong  if possible?

Comment: @hny2015 well, I'm comparing what I have and you and at the moment I don't see what can cause the error. Could you edit the post and provide the complete error traceback and point out the line where it is failing? Thanks.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vineet-mrgreen/ad4a0d3928addb333fb5 , here we go. now I plan to start from scratch to see if it works. but in the mean time you can have a look at the error.

Comment: the main issue is I get this - Error: [$injector:nomod], which means It cant even find it, how is this even possible. This means I am calling it incorrectly and I cannot see how?

Comment: @hny2015 it's kind of weird. Have you tried to start it from scratch - remove node_modules, run `npm cache clean` and reinstall your dependencies?

Comment: xe - Nope, we now are using mock-server now for the tests. Devs helped me out with setting this up. that didnt worked for me which is sad.

Comment: The reason for this misbehaviour is the driver function.

Instead of using 

```browser.driver.get('http://localhost:8580');```

use 

```browser.get('http://localhost:8580');```

etc.

Comment: @TimothyDalton this unfortunately does not solve the issue. I placed log statements inside the generated httpMock module (along with all of the above), and they are not even being called. The mock module is simply not being injected for whatever reason - even though debugging protractor.js clearly shows the modules are being injected (code-wise, at least) when Protractor.get is called.